# Equivalent of NSOperationQueue in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, macos, ios

Just wondering if anyone can tell me what the equivalent of NSOperationQueue (from MacOS/iOS) is in c#/.Net.

For those unfamiliar with it, it is a queue of threads. You can set priorities and also concurrent actions and it will work through the queue running how ever many threads you set at a time. Once the thread is complete a new one is loaded.

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.Threading.ThreadPool is similar in function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

Comment: It is similar, but it lacks the ability to set priorities on operations, or to cancel all queued operations. Plus, it is a static class, so you can't make multiple ThreadPool instances with different properties.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've done much C# code, but I used to use [ThreadPools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y366). Makes it real easy, like the `NSOperationQueue`.